# How create edges right after vertex insertion in one SQL query in OrientDB?

Tags: sql, database, orientdb

I have created vertex class Person and edge class friends. After insertion in class Person the query result returns @rid and some kind of other data or properties etc.

[image: OrientDB Studio]

and I want to use this @rid for creating edges between vertices. I want to implement something like:

```
create edge friends 
from (insert into person (name) values("John")) 
to (insert into person (name) values("Ann"))
```

so that I should be able to create edge immediately in one query.

I am inserting batch data with prepared statement, that's why I can't get @rid after insertion, and because of that I want to make it in one query. I suppose it would be faster as well.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use batch scripts and LET statements:

```
LET $alice = insert into person (name) values("Alice");
LET $bob = insert into person (name) values("Bob");
LET $charlie = insert into person (name) values("Charlie");
create edge friends from $alice to $bob;
create edge friends from $bob to $charlie;
```

If you do it from Studio, make sure you select the BATCH mode.

Comment: That is by variables. let me try it.

Comment: Works in Studio, but not working with preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

Comment: It is throwing NullPointerException. This is maybe because of sometimes INSERT returns null?

Comment: Which OrientDB version are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.0.2. The reason of NullPointerException I am afraid prepared statement is being closed after one query, and is not making queries in batch mode.

Comment: uhm, that's strange, I tried my script on 3.0.x branch and it works fine. Could you please try https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-community/3.0.3-SNAPSHOT/ ? There is a chance that it is an already fixed bug